# как привязать определенное действие к bpm музыки?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю музыкальную игру, и мне нужно чтобы объекты появлялись в такт музыки, это вроде не сложно. Но мне так же нужно добавить оффсет, чтоб сместить появление объектов и они появлялись в такт музыки. У меня вроде получилось это сделать, но я не уверен првильно ли я это сделал сточки зрения оптимизации и читаемости кода. Можете пожалуйста посоветовать, что можно улучшить или переписать? Надеюсь понятно описал))

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cube_Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timer, coolDown, bpm, offset;

    //двумерный масив с информацией о номере файла, bpm и оффсете
    private float[,] musics =  { { 1, 2 }, { 135.04f, 200f }, { 0.020f, 0.582f } };

    public AudioClip deadlocked, fortuna;

    private bool isOffset;

    //в старте я случайно выбераю файл музыки
    private void Start()
    {
        float clip = Random.Range(0, musics.GetLength(0) - 1);

        if (clip == 0)
        {
            PlayAudio(deadlocked, musics[1, 0], musics[2, 0]);
        }
        else if(clip == 1)
        {
            PlayAudio(fortuna, musics[1, 1], musics[2, 1]);
        }

        isOffset = false;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        coolDown = 60 / bpm;

        Timer();
    }

    public void PlayAudio(AudioClip clip, float _bpm, float _offset)
    {
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(clip);
        bpm = _bpm;
        offset = _offset;
    }

    //таймер, который припервом ударе убирает от этого самого таймера величену равную оффету
    private void Timer()
    {
        if (timer > 0)
        {
            if (isOffset == false)
            {
                timer -= Time.deltaTime + offset;
                isOffset = true;
            }
            else
                timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (timer <= 0)
        {
            print("End");
            timer = coolDown;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## НЕ ОТВЕТ

Это не совсем тот ответ который ты ждешь, но, возможно, тебе будет полезно.

Есть такая игра - Crypt of the NecroDancer. Там уже было реализованно +- то, что ты хочешь.

Там вместе с игрой есть утилитка для анализа ритма музыки. Если ты добавляешь кастомную песню в игру то она сначала пропускает песню через эту утилиту, а на выходе получает некий текстовый файл который и отображает ритм песни.

Эта утилитка тебе поможет только если тебе нужен 1 единый ритм на всю песню (не ритм каждого отдельного инструмента, а именно на всю песню)

И т.к. она внешняя, вероятнее всего на нее можно найти документацию в интернете и понять как анализировать ее формат и использовать в твоей игре.

Comment: Оно бы влезло в комменты, не в один, так в два. Перенесите в комментарии.

Comment: А можно немного по подробнее? Как она называеться?

Comment: @aepot просто это альтернативный путь который избавляет от надобности создания оффсета. Да и в принципе снимает кучу проблем с ручным подбором bps. не уверен что есть смысл перемещать в комментарии т.к. ответ хоть и "не ответ", но отвечает как именно пойти альтернативным путем к конечной цели

Comment: @Terix скачай пиратку и поиграйся. Или купи лицуху, на нее в стиме скидка сейчас 80% еще 30 часов будет. И в одной из папок игры будет эта утилитка. AMPLIFIED PACK можешь не покупать.

Comment: спасибо, пойду разбираться

Comment: @Terix Как успехи? Может поделишся результатами своей работы в своем вопросе?)

Comment: решение нашел в одной статье, посвященной этой теме. Воспользоваться той утилитой не получилось, ибо просто не знаю как подключить ее к проэкту юнити, по спасибо за совет

Comment: я вангую что в ту утилитку можно пихать музыку просто через аргументы к экзешнику. Типо путь к утилитке + путь к файлу в консоли и энтер. Возможно с какими-то другими параметрами которые достаточно просто узнать.  Там больший интерес к тем текстовым файлам которые утилитка генерит - как именно их расшифровать. Ну и юнити работать должен уже как раз таки именно с теми текстовыми файлами которые генерятся утилиткой.